# How to redraw DataGridView from another form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, datagridview

I have a list of items that have a name, price and quantity value.
This list is stored in one form, and this form also had an edit button, so that when a user clicks on a row, they are able to edit this item inside another form that pops up.

I have my code working so that the item changes in the list, however it seems like the DataGridView just isn't updating when the list is changed.
When I edit an item, and add in a new row, it shows the changed values.

Here is my code for my first form:

```
private void EditButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EditForm editForm = new EditForm();
        if (BasketGrid.RowCount > 0)
        {
            editForm.Show();
        }
    }
```

So this juts sets up the button so that it shows the other form.
"BasketGrid" is my DataGridView, that is also given a public initialization at the beginning of my code (Called dgv)

```
public void EditOkBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.newName = editNameBox.Text;
    decimal price;
    int quant;
    if (decimal.TryParse(editPriceBox.Text, out price))
    {
        this.newPrice = price;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect format for price");
    }
    if(int.TryParse(editQuantBox.Text, out quant))
    {
        this.newQuantity = quant;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect format for quantity");
    }
    foreach (OrderItem o in basketForm.GetList().ToList())
    {
        string listName = basketForm.getListName();
        if (listName == o.ProductName)
        {
            o.ProductName = this.newName;
            o.ProductPrice = this.newPrice;
            o.ProductQuantity = this.newQuantity;
        }
    }
    this.Close();
}
```

This is my "Edit Button" in my secondary form. This grabs my itemlist from my other form via a method, and compares the product name in of the orderitem in the list, and the listname that the user has selected from the row.

I'd created 'basketForm' as a new object of my other form, so I can access methods and stuff.
I've tried to use basketForm.dgv.Refresh(); but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: How do you draw your DataGridView, which you want to redraw?

Comment: @Rekshino As far as I'm aware, the DataGridView draws itself when the datasource is updated.

Comment: You mean if you reset the datasource the DataGridView will be updated? ;) DataSource=null;DataSource=newValue;

Comment: @Rekshino That is another thing I have tried, underneath the foreach loop in the second form. Unless I'm putting that in the wrong place?

Comment: You should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in `OrderItem` class.

Comment: Have you also set the dgv.DataSource to null?

Answer (score 1):

You can use BindingSource and ShowDialog...

Example:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();

    List<YourData> yourData = new List<YourData>();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bindingSource.DataSource = yourData;

        dgv.DataSource = bindingSource;
    }
}
```

Changes will be reflected to your grid like this...

```
private void EditButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EditForm editForm = new EditForm(yourData);

    if (BasketGrid.RowCount > 0)
    {
        editForm.ShowDialog(this);

        bindingSource.ResetBindings(true);
    }
}

//Change your Data in EditForm whatever you want
public partial class EditForm : Form
{
    List<YourData> yourData;
    public EditForm(List<YourData> yourData)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.yourData = yourData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface in the `OrderItem` class. This will update only one value in `DataGridView`, instead of updating the entire collection, which may be critical if the collection is very large and its binding may trigger actions, like validation, etc.

```
class OrderItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    // other fields : price, quantity

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (value != name)
            {
                name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    // other properties: Price, Quantity

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Also you have to use [BindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx) class instead of `List`. It supports two-way data-binding mechanism.